# Undefined Column | Laravel Eloquent Reverse Like

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, sql-like

I want to get all rows that have their column is a part of my string (not the inverse)

I did this query,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'string' LIKE CONCAT('%', column, '%')
```

The query works correctly when running directly on the server via an SQL querying tool.

However, i'm using eloquent ORM, i tried to do the following :

```
$results = MODEL::where('my_string','like',"CONCAT('%',column, '%')")->get();
```

It throws this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "my_string" does not exist
```

LINE 1:

Please NOTE that i'm not looking for this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%string%'
```

Comment: From the error, It seems you do not have column `my_string` in the table. please check it.

Comment: Yes, i know, i'm not looking for "my_string" as a column, but i'm looking for the column's content in the "my_string"

Comment: Since you already have a working sql statement, You can use `Raw Expressions`. It should be something right this `MODEL::whereRaw("'string' LIKE CONCAT('%', column, '%')");` . try this one and let me know the result.

Comment: EXACTLY! it works! perfect!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comment above. If you already got a working sql statement. You can use `Raw Expressions`

```
MODEL::whereRaw("'string' LIKE CONCAT('%', column, '%')");
```

For more information, http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries in `Raw Expressions` section